# VB.NET Permission to access local user's folders

Tags: vb.net, user-permissions, file-access

In my VB.NET app, an AD user(*timmy*) can login and access his exchange a/c through Outlook. Outlook is launched using a Process.

When user tries to double click an attachment of PDF file, Edge being and to-be the default PDF viewer opens up but fails to load the file. It shows error message :
[image]

The reason I can think of is: user *timmy* doesn't have access to user *cbembinster's* local files.

How can I give access to timmy to access local user's files and folders ?
Can anyone give any idea on how to solve this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When *cbembinster* runs the application, does it still run as *timmy*?

Comment: Shouldn't the attachment have been saved somewhere the appropriate users have access to? Does the file actually exist there?

Comment: @kush, when cbembinster runs the application, it runs as cbembinster and his profile loaded,

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I can't find the file downloaded any time. I can navigate till C:\Users\CADTI\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache or maybe some time Content.Outlook, but I don't find the file in the folder.